# r dataframe correlation coefficient and p value

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df with columns

```
Parameter  A  B
```

I want to get the pearson correlation coeeficient and the corresponding p value as two columns appended to the above, so the result will look like

```
Parameter A B corr_coeff p-value
```

I tried

```
ddply(df, .(Parameter), summarise, "corr_coeff" = cor(A, B, method = "pearson"))
```

but can get only the correlation coefficient.Please let me know of a solution

Comment: Try `Hmisc::rcorr`.

Answer (score 1):

An option would be `cor.test`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   group_by(Parameter) %>%
   summarise(out = list(tibble(cor.test(A, B)[c("statistic", "p.value")]))) %>%
   unnest
```